# java sourceCompatibility with groovy plugin and gradle in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, groovy

i have a gradle project with groovy plugin. groovy also cross-compiles java classes. there's **no java plugin**, just `apply plugin: 'groovy'` and later `apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'`

intellij imported the project but it uses sourceCompatibility < 1.8 (there is only java 8 installed in the system). `gradlew build` works without any problems.

what to add to .gradle file to make intellij uses 1.8 sourceCompatibility?

Answer (score 0):

If you've added the `idea` plugin, you should be able to add the following to `build.gradle`:

```
idea {
    project {
        jdkName "1.8"
        languageLevel "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: i added that after all plugins apply. after doing `refresh` in gradle window nothing changed